# Protect wp-login.php for all but with conditional logic to allow one referring URL to skip .htaccess login

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

We're all familiar with this setup for protecting the wp-login.php file by now.

```
<Files wp-login.php>
    AuthName "Restricted Area"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /<some-path>/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
    ErrorDocument 401 "Authorization Required"
</Files>
```

That works great.

But I also have another login in a shortcode (partial code below) ...

`wp_login_form( array( 'echo' => false, 'remember' => false, 'value_remember' => false ) );`

... that I use on a different page - lets call it:

https://somesite.com/otherloginpage/

Is there any way I can have /otherloginpage/ skip the .htaccess login?

I previously found this here:

https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/

```
## ALLOW ACCESS WITH PASSWORD OR NO PASSWORD FOR SPECIFIC IP/HOSTS
AuthType basic
AuthName "Ooops! Temporarily Under Construction..."
AuthUserFile /.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
Require valid-user      # password prompt for everyone else
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 192.168.64.5   # Your, the developers IP address
Allow from w3.org      # css/xhtml check jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/
Allow from googlebot.com   # Allows google to crawl your pages
Satisfy Any        # no password required if host/ip is Allowed
```

But it doesn't work for exactly what I want to do.  I believe I need to set a referrer somehow rather than a domain/IP.

Also, can this be added to within the `<files>` section?  It seems to cause errors at the `Order Deny,Allow` line.

Any ideas on how to get a referring URL into some logic to skip the .htaccess login requirements?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution thanks to Reddit

```
<Files wp-login.php>
   <If "!(%{HTTP_REFERER} -strmatch 'https://url.com/page/')">
    AuthName "Restricted Area"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /path/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
    ErrorDocument 401 "Authorization Required"
   </If>
</Files>
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if